# TypeScript Generics Priority

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

UPDATE: The issue is a limitation of TypeScript, the issue is on Typescripts GitHub now: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47440

I currently have the following code:

```
class Table<T,> {
   constructor(records: T[], columns: Column<T>[]) { ... }
}

class Column<T> {
   constructor(name: string, transformer: (item: T) => string) { ... }
   addTooltip(transformer: (item: T) => string): this { ... }
}

class Building {
   constructor (public name: string) {}
}

const buildings = [
   new Building("test"),
   new Building("station")
];
```

I want to create a table, without having to specify that `T` is of type `Building`.

This works so far, because typescript can infer the type from the buildings array and it works. Even in the `transformer` of the Column, I still get type suggestions.

```
const table = new Table(buildings, [
    new Column("Name", building => building.name)
]);
```

But when I use `addTooltip`, typescript can't figure out what `T` is and completely freaks out, because the `Column` assumes that `T` is `unknown`.

```
const table = new Table(buildings, [
    new Column("Name", building => building.name),
    new Column("Name", building => building.name).addTooltip(t => t.name)
]);
```

Is there a way to tell TypeScript to use the type of its `records` constructor parameter as a source for T, ignoring what the columns think `T` is - without using `new Table<Building>(...)`? I know that we could use `columns: Column<any>[]`, but then the type checking in the Columns would not work.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqYCMQFMA8sA0A+aBvAUNEdMAPYB2EALgE4CuwVpNAFDcmTQCYQBccAbQC6GEqRB0AtpX4BhcVPLoswgJR5oAegBU0AHQHo2zdAC++c-lCQY8idOV5CxMpVoMmrcmEnJ+1GgBLcgBzUVowSgAzZl8afhZAqmRJflh1AF4cAOCQ9VwtbQM9YzNnIjAuLlhScSpAgAcWCOjY5HjoROTUuEzs2lzVfioAC0CYAvYqOhpyaFHxgG4yy2soaAAhOkCQLlynFwoAj2ZOhrokQOBob19-AdD881WjqmgEbd3cmAzoAXKbsgAO6bT57UIsABEyWokNUGAB5GBoJ24JCUOoYHqFDh+CEi3wVle80QKGgvyRIPgSGQLA+qO+on+xEBILsiihADkfMhIaJ6V9QuScAK0XpbshVHjVASiW4STSAEzk1lwUm00WMv6I5Hs6Rcnl895g-ZZY0M0LinnwnVshT6yHc3xGzVCs2ukJW3yqPSVaq1ED1JpvM1UL2S6UEoA)

Comment: I have to admit I don't understand why it doesn't work. The type of `new Column("Name", building => building.name)` should be `Column<Building>` to my mind, so calling `addTooltip` on it should know it's a `Building`. But **I** don't write the TypeScript compiler and I'm sure it's more complicated than that. :-D

Comment: It does look like you've reached the limits of what type inference can do. Once you add `addTooltip()`, TS can't really figure out the type parameter for the constructor, as it'd have to infer things backwards.

Comment: @biziclop - Oh, that backwards thing is a good point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I understand it. Basically the order in which type inference should happen is: `Table -> addTooltip() -> Building`, but as `addTooltip()` depends on `Building`, this fails.

Comment: I have a version is closer but I don't think I can get any closer https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqYCMQFMA8sA0A+aBvAUNEdMAPYB2EALgE4CuwVpNAFDcmTQCYQBccAbQC6GEqRB0AtpX4BhcVPLoswgJR5oAegBU0AHQHo2zdAC++c6Egx5E6cryFiZSrQZNW5MJOT9qNAEtyAHNRWjBKADNmHxp+FgCqZEl+WHUAXhx-IOD1XC1tAz1jMyciMC4uWFJxKgCAB2UWKgALAL5oW0VUOnIAa3JSAHdyLDCaCIhomlj4xOTUjKzaHNU5BXtYHHz2KjoacmhW9oBuUvN8KyhoACE6AJAuHMdnCn93ZmgWerokAOBoF4fH4ViE8uYLi5qNAEPdHjkYOloAIyoDkENbnCniEWAAiJLUXGqDD4IQnfCXN5UI6IFAAJmgSPI6LgtOQLFhD2xwQgohRxDRGK60jxADlvMhcaJOfCQoycDLuXogchiajmUKNuQxRKpTCsc9MvquTllRLVHoKlUaiA6vVmvKjmafKpSapyUA

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with indirect `T` inference

Comment: This does look like a limitation of contextual inference; generally flow doesn't happen backwards through multiple function calls; you tend to get at most one.  Maybe ones that return `this` could be handled more intelligently, but I'd guess this just isn't a thing for now.  All I can think of are workarounds, like making [the constructor take multiple transformers](https://tsplay.dev/w2Ex8W).  Do you want an answer with workarounds?  Or one with a simple "no, this doesn't work, sorry"?

Comment: @jcalz I would like to know why it does not work with links to ts issues. Looking forward for your answer

Comment: @captain-yossarian Heh as soon as I start looking I find [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47440), so I think any canonical discussion should happen there.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell you how to do what you actually want to do (and what I'd actually want to do), but I can give you a couple of options for workarounds.

1. You could have a static method on `Column` that does the combined operation of creating the `Column` and adding the tooltip.
2. You could have a static method on `Column` that accepts a `Column` and adds a tooltip to it.
3. You could have a standalone function that does what the static method in #2 does.

When you do that, the inference works.

#### #1

```typescript
static withTooltip<T>(
    name: string,
    transformer: (item: T) => string,
    tooltipTransformer: (item: T) => string,
): Column<T> {
    const col = new Column(name, transformer);
    col.addTooltip(tooltipTransformer);
    return col;
}
```

Then building the array is:

```typescript
const table = new Table(buildings, [
    new Column("Name", building => building.name),
    Column.withTooltip("Name", building => building.name, t => t.name),
]);
```

#### #2

```typescript
static plusTooltip<T>(col: Column<T>, transformer: (item: T) => string): Column<T> {
    col.addTooltip(transformer);
    return col;
}
```

Then building the array is:

```typescript
const table = new Table(buildings, [
    new Column("Name", building => building.name),
    Column.plusTooltip(new Column("Name", building => building.name), t => t.name),
]);
```

#### #3

...is just #2 but as a function rather than static method.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqYCMQFMA8sA0A+aBvAUNEdMAPYB2EALgE4CuwVpNAFDcmTQCYQBccAbQC6GEqRB0AtpX4BhcVPLoswgJR5oAegBU0AHQHo2zdAC++c-lCQY8idOV5CxMpVoMmrcmEnJ+1GgBLcgBzUVowSgAzZl8afhZAqmRJflh1AF4cAOCQ9VwtbQM9YzNnIjAuLlhScSpAgAcWCOjY5HjoROTUuEzs2lzVfioAC0CYAvYqOhpyaFHxgG4y4mhqMHrgaAB3JJGausblFnLV6G9ffwHQjFPVlogYmjiEpJS0vrXrsLviJkOGrAaJFHm0Ol13r1oFkvkEbqchtA7IpHAQzi4KNQxCBoedkNskQppCwLshwsDWs92qpFr8iGQQHpKtVaiB6k1-mzGkCQU84jS6dApjM5gzaatzKt1ptoA0JBADlyGscGXIiUpYFhybywa9uh9of04Xk1fYNTg0ejsUyqor2c0KaCqTQBVahchprNseLiOZLNYoNAAEJ0QIgLi5JwYtz0RjMToNOhIQJbUlXY35P34KyYqjQBCh8O5GAZaACU7kfHBwsR0IsABEyWo9dUt1WlYJIbDtZCDelgQoLfwQlpObc80QKFxHbgk+QLAL3eLonL7aryOJ9YAcj5kPXRIui6FDfma7k9KTVMOBWOsVQ5wAmadV+BIeeHnsQFcV9fqhs73x91PJdjxhD9z0vNtiA3cg9DlOgFVZe0Zxg-9dyA8DQJwTCQgvXdW3mE8qDw3xW1OGC9F2UY7UaNDAIPM8sOAo9cNJcIiJI5AyKEAUgA)

Comment: But hopefully someone better at TypeScript than I can provide a better solution.